# Flex: Any control to select month?

Tags: apache-flex

Is there any Flex control to select months (any)?

Right now I'm using a DateField, and allow the user to select any date in a month to select that month.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe try ComboBox? or List?

So here is the sample with ComboBox:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:WindowedApplication xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"
    xmlns:controls="radekg.*">
    <mx:Form>
        <mx:FormItem label="Select date:">
            <controls:DateComboBox id="dcb" change="trace(dcb.selectedMonth)" />
        </mx:FormItem>
    </mx:Form>
</mx:WindowedApplication>
```

And radekg/DateComboBox.as

```
package radekg {
    import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
    import mx.controls.ComboBox;
    import mx.formatters.DateFormatter;

    public class DateComboBox extends ComboBox {

        public function DateComboBox() {
            super();
            var formatter:DateFormatter = new DateFormatter();
            formatter.formatString = "MMMM";
            dataProvider = new ArrayCollection();
            for (var i:int=0; i<12; i++) {
                var date:Date = new Date(1971,i,1);
                ArrayCollection(dataProvider).addItem(
                    { label: formatter.format(date), data: date }
                );
            }
            selectedIndex = 0;
        }

        public function get selectedMonth():Number {
            return (selectedItem.data as Date).month;
        }
        public function set selectedMonth(value:Number):void {
            selectedIndex = value;
        }

    }
}
```

It is just a sample :) Hope it helps.

Comment: you could also do it maybe with a tile-list?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a compacted DateChooser, something like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:WindowedApplication xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml">


    <mx:DateChooser id="dateChooser" height="31"/>

</mx:WindowedApplication>
```

And in an Init function:

```
//import com.adobe.fiber.runtime.lib.DateTimeFunc;

public function init():void {
//    var days:int = DateTimeFunc.daysInMonth(new Date() );
    var disabledDays:Array = [ 0, 1, 2, 3 , 4, 5, 6 ];
    this.view.dateChooser.disabledDays = disabledDays;
    this.view.dateChooser.yearNavigationEnabled = true;
    this.view.dateChooser.minYear = 2010;
}
```

I am not sure that disabling days is somehow useful, but as we are hiding days, the sub panel is useless.

Note that I specified a min Year and enabled the Year Selector.
I left commented a userful function when working with calendars :)